# How do I install Turicreate on macOS, Python 3.8?

Tags: python, pip, turi-create

I try to run this on macOS:

pip3.8 install turicreate

I have:

Python 3.8.6

and pip 24.0 from (python 3.8)

Update: The initial output showed
installing to build/bdist.macosx-14-arm64/wheel

Reopened the terminal as I thought maybe it didn't open with Rosetta, now I get same error message but with
installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel

I am using this on the opened using Rosetta terminal.

I still get this error message:

```
          SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
  !!
  
          ********************************************************************************
          Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
          Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
          standards-based tools.
  
          See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    self.initialize_options()
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  
  
  
          ==================================================================================
          TURICREATE ERROR
  
          If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
          for your system.
  
          Supported Platforms:
              * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
              * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
  
          Support Python Versions:
              * 2.7
              * 3.5
              * 3.6
              * 3.7
              * 3.8
  
          Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
              `pip install -U pip`
  
          ==================================================================================
```

I got this error with my initial python and pip versions updated both to the requirements of turicreate.

I tried using Rosetta and checking my anaconda version which is x86_64.

Tried `pip install wheel`, `pip install -U turicreate`.

Comment: Supported Platforms: macOS 10.12+ **x86_64**. You have: macosx-14-**arm64**.

Comment: I reopened the terminal and ran it again, now it is

installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel and I get the same error message other than that